# What's the best way to populate data from a sql db. Table or gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, webforms

I'm wondering what's the best way to populate data from a sql db to a page(using webforms) if I want something looking like a table or a gridview where I can double click on each row and open up a new window with some of the data from the sql db for that specific row?

I don't want to look in the database everytime I double click on each row, so I want the data I fetch the first time to be kept the whole session.

Are there any neat tutorials for this scenario?

Best regards
Joe the noob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get your data out the database and put it into a `DataTable` or `DataView` (if want to store multiple sets) - stick with `DataTables` for now.

If you want the object to persist between postbacks you can then use `ViewSatate["myDataTable"] = myDataTableObject` or `Session["myDataTable"] = myDataTableObject`. I tend to use `Session` because I'm old fashioned and I sometimes move the data to another page.

So you want something like this in your `Page_Load`

```
var myDataTable = new DataTable();
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    Session["myDataTable"] = null;
    //clear the session on a fresh page view and probably you 
    //want code here to go get the data from the database, ie:
    myDataTable = GetDataFromDatabase();
}
else
{
    if (Session["myDataTable"] != null)
    {
        myDataTable = (DataTable)Session["myDataTable"];
    }
    else
    {
        myDataTable = GetDataFromDatabase();
    }
}


private DataTable GetDataFromDatabase()
{
    //returns DataTable populated from Database
}
```

You will want to improve the above, it's not ideal code, simply written in that way to illustrate the idea. Also, you need to clear the object when refreshing the data, be careful now as this can be easy to trip yourself up.

Comment: What is the best to use on the page, is it table or gridview if I want to double click on each row and open up a new window with some of the data from the sql db for that specific row?

Comment: A GridView, you can use `OnRowCreated` to hide/change row sizes etc. And if you need to change data that you're displaying without affecting the source use `OnRowDataBound`, you can also use that one to add in dynamic controls for each row (dynamic controls need to be recreated on PostBack - another minefield).

Comment: Ok, but what about tables? which one would you prefer to use?, lets say you will get about 10 rows of data with perhaps 6-7 columns. These rows must be clickable so a new window opens up together with a new sql query.

Comment: The GridView will create a table, from there you can do pretty much anything with it. Here's an example to get you going: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/AddDynamicallyControlstoGri-d74fe84f

Comment: Thanks for the help! Perhaps stackoverflow needs a noob section for novice questions, since two people already voted to close my question :S